# Почему вместе с worker-ом и без него, скорость выполнения задачи одинаковая?

Tags: node.js, многопоточность, promise, асинхронность, worker

### app.js

```
const func = (array) =>{
    return script(array)
}

const main = () =>{
    performance.mark('start')
    console.log(func([10,4,2,1,5]))
    performance.mark('end')
    performance.measure('main', 'start', 'end')
    console.log(`Скорость работы составила: ${performance.getEntriesByName('main').pop().duration.toFixed()}ms`)
}

function script(array){
    let result = []
    array.map(el =>{
        result.push(el % 2 == 0)
    })
    for(i = 1; i < 1099999999; i++){
        i**4
    }
    return result
}

main()
```

**Консоль**

> [ true, true, true, false, false ]

> Скорость работы составила: 2540ms

---

### worker-app.js

```
const { Worker } = require('worker_threads')

const workerFunc = (array) =>{
    performance.mark('start')
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
        const worker = new Worker('./worker.js', {
            workerData: array
        })

        worker.on('message', msg =>{
            performance.mark('end')
            performance.measure('main', 'start', 'end')
            console.log(`Скорость работы составила: ${performance.getEntriesByName('main').pop().duration.toFixed()}ms`)
            resolve(msg)
        })

        worker.on('error', err =>{
            reject(err)
        })

    }).then(data =>{
        console.log(data)
    }).catch(err =>{
        console.error(err)
    })
}


const main = async () =>{
    await workerFunc([10,4,2,1,5])
}



main()
```

**Консоль**

> [ true, true, true, false, false ]

> Скорость работы составила: 2613ms

---

### worker.js

```
const { parentPort, workerData } = require('worker_threads')
const { script } = require('./script')

parentPort.postMessage(script(workerData))
```

---

### script.js

```
function script(array){
    let result = []
    array.map(el =>{
        result.push(el % 2 == 0)
    })

    // нагрузка на процессор
    for(i = 1; i < 1099999999; i++){
        i**4
    }
    return result
}

module.exports = { script }
```

---

Comment: А почему она должна быть разная? Что вы вообще пытаетесь измерять?

Comment: Сейчас я просматриваю курс по Node.js. Смотрел как работает многопоточность, автор рассказывает, что при этом методе (используя worker) работа выполняется в 2-3 быстрее. У него так и есть, но у меня это не выходит. Хотя копировал его код та же самая проблема

Comment: Ну довольно странно мерять не зная что и зачем ты измеряешь. И вообще измерять скорость работы пустого цикла на миллиард итераций довольно глупо. Это скорее измерение работы оптимизатора кода.

Comment: В первом случае у вас работает основной поток и выполняет всю работу. Во втором случае у вас работает один веркер, так же выполняя всю ту же работу. В это время основной поток ожидает пока веркер завершиться. Скорость работы одинакова так как в обоих случаях работает всего один поток. Скорость может расти, если например вы запустите несколько веркеров и каждый из них выполнит часть работы. Или пока веркер выполняет работу, основной поток может не просто ждать его завершения, а делать какую либо свою работу, в том числе так же загружая процессор (если конечно ядер больше 1)